# Can metal ball casters be covered?

Tags: repair, furniture

[image: metal tread ball furniture caster]

Can I do anything to these casters (on my parsons dining room chairs) to make them safe on solid oak hardwood floors? Maybe adding some sort of a rubber ring to the raised tread or even covering them completely so they don't roll at all?
(btw...removing them is not an option.)

I am also considering trying out this on the very remote off chance it could work on my type casters: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004SOJIZC/ref=ox_sc_act_title_7?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SOJIZC)

Comment: Why not change them out to urethane ones?

Comment: as @shirlockhomes Pointed out, it will most likely be both more cost effective and durable to completely replace the casters with something else non-marring, that it would be to attempt to adapt them. IME Purpose Built > Home Brewed 99% of the time.

Comment: Try an area rug. We had the same issue last year when we changed out tile and put in hardwood. We tried new casters but were worried that they might leave dents in the wood. At first a area rug was out of the question. But on a whim decided to try one and was pleasantly surprised at what it added to the room.

Answer (score 2):

You might like "caster cups"

[image]

You can get them in a variety of colours, sizes and materials including transparent plastic.

---

For chairs that need to be slid in and out from under a table, you might need a type of caster cup specifically intended for that purpose

> The only castor cup where the wheels stay in the cup when furniture is moved

- From advertisement for "MagiGLIDE CASTOR CUP 4 PACK". I have not tried this and don't know if it is suitable for the intended use or whether the claims are justified.

Castor cups are usually cheap - it doesn't hurt to try them on one chair. You don't lose much if they turn out to be unsuitable.

Comment: My interpretation is that the OP wants to be able to move his chairs :-) . Cups are fine for sofas, tables, etc. but just try sitting at a table if you can't slide the chair in and out a bit.

Comment: @Carl:  OP wrote *"or even covering them completely **so they don't roll at all**?"* - also chairs in caster cups can slide approximately as easily as chairs without casters do - though the cups might slip off in some circumstances.

Comment: @Carl: Answer updated to address your point.

Comment: I am in a catch 22 kinda situation. 1. Area rug is not an option. 2. Changing casters will be practically impossible. 3. Taking them off (which I wouldn't mind) is not an option since the skirt length includes casters. I don't need to ROLL the chairs but want to be able to lift them and move them around the way one does regular dining rm. chairs. If there was a snug "sock" type contraption I can slip over the casters, it would be great. The only question I have about "MagiGLIDE CASTOR CUP 4 PACK" is if the chairs can be lifted without the gliders slipping off.